# Use Ajax to send image from User to Flask for classification

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, deployment

I want to take an image as input from user throught HTML input tag and want to send that image to Flask using Ajax so that I can classify that image using my saved Keras model after some preprocessing steps and then return the predicted class to Ajax to display it on screen.
But I am facing problem to get the image in Flask from Ajax for further processing.

Here are my HTML and Ajax

```
<form id="main_form">
  <input type="file" name="imgtoupload", id="imgtoupload">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<h2>Class Prediction is: <span id="result"></span></h2>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#main_form").on('submit', function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        var send_data = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/predict',
            data: send_data,
            success:function(data){

                $("#result").text(data.name);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
```

I want to use that input image from Ajax as an array in this predict function in python for further processing.

Comment: I don't know about Flask, but you'll need to add `contentType: false` and `processData: false` in the options of your jQuery AJAX request in order for the file data to be encoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can import image in Flask like this :

```
from flask import Flask, request
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict(): 
    file = request.files['file']
```

After that, you can save and process the file on flask app

Here are my HTML

```
<form action="score" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```